# C++ исключить функцию из перегрузки

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

есть некоторый класс:

```
        template<
            typename T,
            typename = typename std::enable_if<
                std::is_arithmetic<T>::value ||
                std::is_same<T, std::string>::value>::type>
        class NBTTag 
        {
        public:

            ...

            std::vector<char> toBuffer() const noexcept
            {
                std::size_t alignment = 0;
                std::vector<char> buffer{};

                ...
                alignment = setValueToBuffer(buffer, alignment);

                return buffer;
            }


            std::size_t setValueToBuffer(std::vector<char>& buffer, std::size_t alignment, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, std::size_t>::type* = nullptr) const noexcept
            {
                ...
            }

            std::size_t setValueToBuffer(std::vector<char>& buffer, std::size_t alignment, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, std::string>::value, std::string>::type* = nullptr) const noexcept
            {
                ...
            }

        };
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы когда приходил в шаблонный класс числовой тип, то вызывался бы первый вариант перегрузки, а когда std::string второй вариант, но я уже второй час бьюсь с этим... На данный момент получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'type' 
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'type' 
Error   C2039   'type': is not a member of 'std::enable_if<false,std::string>'  
Error   C2039   'type': is not a member of 'std::enable_if<false,size_t>'
```

Может кто-нибудь подскажет как эт можно элегантнее реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для нужного Вам поведения, `enable_if` должен применяться совместно с выводом типа
Если нужно минимум изменений, то можно сделать так:

```
template<typename U = T>
std::size_t setValueToBuffer(std::vector<char>& buffer, std::size_t alignment, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<U>::value, std::size_t>::type* = nullptr) const noexcept
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, U>::value, "wrong types");
    //...
}

template<typename U = T>
std::size_t setValueToBuffer(std::vector<char>& buffer, std::size_t alignment, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, std::string>::value, std::string>::type* = nullptr) const noexcept
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, U>::value, "wrong types");
    //...
}
```

**UPD 01:**
Возможно, стоит вынести функционал `setValueToBuffer` в отдельный шаблон структуры и специализировать его для нужных типов.

```
namespace details
{

template<typename T>
struct SetValueToBufferAux;//Общий шаблон не определяется


}//end of namespace details    

template<typename T,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_arithmetic<T>::value ||
        std::is_same<T, std::string>::value>::type>
class NBTTag 
{
    //Вам точно нужен enable_if в параметрах шаблона класса?
    //Если нет, то можно поменять на static_assert:
    //static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value || std::is_same<T, std::string>::value, "wrong type");
public:

    //...

    std::size_t setValueToBuffer(std::vector<char>& buffer, std::size_t alignment) const noexcept
    {
        return details::SetValueToBufferAux<T>()(*this, buffer, alignment);//Просто делегируем вызов
    }

private:
    friend class details::SetValueToBufferAux<T>;//Если SetValueToBufferAux должен иметь доступ к приватным членам
};

//Специализации SetValueToBufferAux для нужных типов
namespace details
{

template<>
struct SetValueToBufferAux<int>
{
    std::size_t operator() (NBTTag<int> const & tag, std::vector<char>& buffer, std::size_t alignment) const noexcept
    {
        //...
        return 0;
    }
};

template<>
struct SetValueToBufferAux<std::string>
{
    std::size_t operator() (NBTTag<std::string> const & tag, std::vector<char>& buffer, std::size_t alignment) const noexcept
    {
        //...
        return 0;
    }
};


//Если нужно добавить другой тип, то просто пишем нужную специализацию.
}//end of namespace details
```

**UPD 02:**
Код Выше заставит Вас писать специализации для КАЖДОГО используемого типа, например, для КАЖДОГО арифметического типа нужно будет предоставить специализацию `SetValueToBufferAux`. Считаю это неприемлемым для данного случая. Можно изменить `SetValueToBufferAux` следующим образом:

```
namespace details
{

//Добавляем дополнительный параметр заданный по-умолчанию
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct SetValueToBufferAux;  

}//end of namespace details   


//Класс NBTTag остается неизменным

namespace details
{

//Специализация для арифметических типов
template<typename T>
struct SetValueToBufferAux<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type>
{
    std::size_t operator() (NBTTag<T> const & tag, std::vector<char>& buffer, std::size_t alignment) const noexcept
    {
        //...
    }
};

//Специализация для отдельного типа
template<>
struct SetValueToBufferAux<std::string>
{
    std::size_t operator() (NBTTag<std::string> const & tag, std::vector<char>& buffer, std::size_t alignment) const noexcept
    {
        //...
    }
};

}//end of namespace details
```

Comment: А если не минимум?
Какой здесь будет наилучший вариант?

Comment: @QuickDzen наилучший не знаю, но для переделки нужно знать требования к этому методу и какие возможности мы имеем.  
1) Нужен ли ему доступ к приватным членам NBTTag?  
2) Версии для int и string взаимоисключающие и не могут  сосуществовать?
3) Допускается ли введение дополнительных сущностей?
4) Доступен if constexpr из C++17?